# How to create intensity mask for heatmap?

Tags: html, gwt, colors, html5-canvas, heatmap

I'm trying to develop heat map, now initially I would have to draw the intensity mask, and since I'm using GWT so I have randomly generated some coordinates and placed my circles ( with required gradience ) at those locations so the output comes out to be circles overlapping each other. And If I look at the intensity mask from [Dylan Vester](http://dylanvester.com/post/Creating-Heat-Maps-with-NET-20-%28C-Sharp%29.aspx), it comes to be very smooth How can I draw my heat map ?? Also how the output is achieved similar to Dylan Vester?? Question also is if I'm drawing circles then how to decide the intensity at the intersection of two or more circles, how they have achieved ?? Here is my code

```
// creating the object for the heat points
        Heat_Point x = new Heat_Point();

    // Variables for random locations
        int Min = 1,Max = 300;
        int randomx,randomy;

    // Generating set of random values
        for( int i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i++ ) {

            // Generating random x and y coordinates
                randomx = Min + (int)(Math.random() * ((Max - Min) + 1));
                randomy = Min + (int)(Math.random() * ((Max - Min) + 1));

            // Drawing the heat points at generated locations 
                x.Draw_Heatpoint(c1, randomx, randomy);


        }
```

And Here is how I'm plotting my heat point that is Heat_Point class

```
Context con1 = c1.getContext2d(); // c1 is my canvas
CanvasGradient x1;
x1 = ((Context2d) con1).createRadialGradient(x,y,10,x,y,20);
x1.addColorStop(0,"black");
x1.addColorStop(1,"white");
((Context2d) con1).beginPath();
((Context2d) con1).setFillStyle(x1);
((Context2d) con1).arc(x,y,20, 0, Math.PI * 2.0, true);
((Context2d) con1).fill();
((Context2d) con1).closePath();`
```

here I was supposed to add some images but I didn't have enough reputation :D :P

Answer (score 0):

I took a quick look at HeatmapJS (http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/) and it seems he uses radial gradients (like you have above) and he also uses opacity and a color filter called "multiply blend" to smooth out the intensity of the colors in the heat map.

His code is quite impressive.  It's open source, so you might want to check it out!